# What are the visual, behavioral similarities and differences between Yellow Fever Mosquito (Aedes aegypti) and the Tiger Mosquito (Aedes albopictus)?

Tags: evolution, zoology, entomology, ecology, pathology

The Tiger and Yellow Fever Mosquito visually look very similar.

Recognizing the difference is important for tracking and controlling the spread of Yellow Fever, Dengue fever and other diseases. Especially important, now that the range of the two have overlapped in the United States.

I have some questions about the commonalities of these mosquitoes.

---

Evolutionarily, How can the similarities be explained?

Why do they both have the black body with white stripes?

What is the best way to tell them apart?

---

*A. aegypti*, the Yellow Fever Mosquito

[image: aegypti, the Yellow Fever Mosquito]

*A. albopictus*, the Tiger Mosquito
[image: albopictus, the Tiger Mosquito]

Comment: Assuming that _Aedes_ is monophyletic, the similarities between them can be explained simply by the fact that they share a very recent common ancestor and are therefore very closely related!

Answer (score 3):

For the best way to tell them apart, see this guide: http://www.cdc.gov/dengue/resources/30Jan2012/comparisondenguevectors.pdf

Specifically, it seems that the silver pattern on the torso is different (lyre-shaped for Yellow Fever Mosquito, more linear for Asian Tiger Mosquito).  Location is probably also an important determinant.

Comment: +1; thoracic markings are the way to do it. I'd recommend adding a photo or image comparing the two (e.g. http://www.nzdl.org/gsdl/collect/who/archives/HASH017f.dir/p010a.gif) to your answer..